# UWP: Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm when using AES & PKCS7

Tags: mobile, uwp, aes

This question is in regard to encryptions/decryptions in a UWP app which works *fine* on a desktop workstation AND a Windows server. In other words, I can encrypt/decrypt on the workstation, send the encrypted data to the server (via a WCF service), and the server will decrypt the data successfully...

Not quite the same for mobile...

To my point... the *same* exact app on a mobile device will encrypt/decrypt data, but the exact same encrypted data will fail to decrypt when copied to the workstation.  I use the exact same SQLite database file on both.

When decryption fails, it shows "Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm".

So encrypted data created from the mobile device cannot be read from the workstation, and vice versa.  But each can encrypt/decrypt their own data.

I am thinking that encryption may work differently on mobile devices.  Maybe PKCS7 is not supported on mobile phones such as the Lumia 650?

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the encrypted data is the same on desktop and mobile?

Comment: @Bite: It would not be.  I am trying to follow proper encryption techniques where the same data encrypted at different times would always result in different encrypted data... this is so that the decryption mechanism cannot be inferred (theoretically), and the data can still be decrypted.

Comment: What API do you use to encrypt and decrypt the data? Can you share the code snippet? May I know what is your OS version for your Lumia650? Have you tried test on another mobile phone?